# Apache ProxyPass exclude. Don't proxy 404 addresses

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy with Apache, and for the most part it is working well with `ProxyPass`. I would like to exclude one of the directories which I understand I can do with the `!` indicator, documented here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse

So I have:

```
ProxyPass /examples !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
```

That works okay if I go to a file in `/examples` which exists, but if I hit an address which results in a 404 error, the request gets proxied rather than just the 404 being returned.

I would rather the 404 is returned. I couldn't see anything about this in the documentation - does anyone know how it can be done? Many thanks!

This is with Apache v2.4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Apache setup a default error document has been defined outside of the /examples location excluded from your ProxyPass. My RHEL 6 has the default:

```
 Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"
 ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
```

Which will result in any 404 message being redirect to `/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.[en | es | de | fr ]` depending and the accept language settings of the browser generating the 404 error.

IN your case that means a request for `/examples/no-such-file` will still be redirected to `http://localhost:3000/`.

Second to you may want to investigate in the meaning of the `ProxyPassReverse`  directive you omitted from your sample config.

Comment: Ah! Yes I see the logic problem there. Complicated a little by the fact that i was some 404's to go through the proxy, that little nugget of information was really useful - thanks! Thanks also for the pointer about `ProxyPassReverse` .